# Can I use Apache HTTPClient without Commons-logging.jar

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm trying to user `Apache HTTPClient` in my project. Here does not required any logging for this application. So Can I use `HTTPClient` without `Commons-logging.jar`. Otherwise it will be a extra unnecessary burden for my distribution package.

Comment: No. https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/dependencies.html

Comment: Brian Roach: Thank You, That simply means, even the application not required logging feature. we have to distribute this `Commons-logging.jar` with distribution package, right?

Comment: Correct; even if you don't configure / want the logging, the http library is still making calls to methods defined in `Commons-logging`. More than likely if it's not there you'll get a runtime error since they state it's required at runtime.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes you can. As Hannes suggested - here is my own HttpClient maven setup:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Next, since `common-logging` is indeed a runtime dependency, you will need to define the SLF4J bridge for `commons-logging`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

And finally, you will of course need to have a valid SLF4J configuration - here is mine:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank You Eugen. I do not use maven. So can i use above trick?

Comment: Well, if you don't use Maven you need to do the same by hand - you'll simply need to make sure that `commons-logging` is not in your classpath, and that the above jars are. Maven just makes things easier - but there's no reason you cannot do the same manually.

Comment: Except the whole question was about *not having to include a dependency* in the distribution ... you're adding three.

Comment: I had another read of the original question - it's asking if it can use the client without the commons-logging jar specifically. My suggestion does add dependencies - of course - you need to have some logging library in there - but not commons-logging. With no commons-logging, a few potential issues are avoided.

Answer (score 5):

You can use slf4j with the JCL bridge. This will forward JCL logging to slf4j. Than you add a slf4j adapter like log back or log4j and configure it properly.

When using maven, do not forget to exclude the JCL dependency.

http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html