# How to fix "No suitable Log implementation" in Quarkus

Tags: quarkus

I have a Quarkus application using native compilation, and when I try to log anything I get the error:

```
Exception message: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: No suitable Log implementation
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could alternatively use:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-apache-httpclient</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

It causes it to package `httpclient` with logging that works with Quarkus.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the discussion [here](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/13528) I used the dependency tree generated by `./mvnw dependency:tree | grep -B 4 "commons-logging"` to find the classes that imported the Apache logging libraries. It turns out for me it was the HTTP client, so I needed to exclude those with this in the pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
  <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
  <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
  <version>4.5.13</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.30</version>
</dependency>
```

This config was provided by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21573641/8246539).